# how to call PositionChanged method manually in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, bing-maps

I have the below event that gets fired upon geocoordinatewatcher object position changed event.

```
 void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)

 {
   //do the stuff here
 }
```

Now when user clicks on any location on the map I want to call the above method and do the same stuff everytime.
Any idea how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either call your event handler manually:

```
var position = new GeoPosition<GeoCoordinate>(DateTimeOffset.Now, new GeoCoordinate(32, 64));

this.watcher_PositionChanged(this, new GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>(position));
```

Or rewrite your event handler to put the logic in another method, then call it:

```
void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    this.UpdatePosition(e.Position);
}

private void UpdatePosition(GeoCoordinate coordinates)
{
    // Do the stuff here
}
```

This way, you just have to call `UpdatePosition` whenever you feel like it. I'd recommend this solution, it's way cleaner than the first one.